# How to center this element in css

Tags: css

I have an image slider on the homepage of my website, and I would like to center the slider.

You can see it at http://www.bolistylus.com

You'll notice that it is a bit off center. Using firebug, I've noticed that the element `<div id="boli_preview" style="text-align: center;">` is actually centered on the page, but the image doesn't go to the very right edge of the element which throws off the shadow and makes it look off center in relation to the rest of the home page.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
.lof-slidecontent{ margin: 0 auto}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `margin: 0 auto;` for the `div` with `id` `lofslidecontent45`. That will center it correctly.